# Awk - check that a field can be converted to an integer

Tags: awk

Only print field if it can be converted to an integer

If I have this sample text file

```
1 cat
2 dog
3 7
4 fish5
5 22
```

I want my awk script to only print the field if it can be converted to an integer.

I don't want rows 1,2 and 4 to be printed.

example awk script

```
BEGIN {
   print "testing conversion to integer on " ARGV[1];
   myinteger = 0;  # my atmept to force this var to an integer
}
 myinteger = $2;
 myinteger != 0 { print $2; }
```

This doesn't work.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Awk has issues calculating strings so:

`awk '$2 + 0 == $2' file.txt`

```
3    7
5    22
```

This also works for me: `awk '$2 + 0' file.txt`

But as Ed Morton pointed out in the comments this would also include strings starting with digits then maybe this is more correct: `awk '/[a-z]/{next}{print $0}' file.txt` i.e. if letter in line go to next line.

Comment: What do you mean by "Awk has issues calculating strings"? Could you give an example? What you posted tests that the input is a real number, not that it's an integer.

Comment: I see the OP has selected this as the correct answer. It is not.`$ echo "1e2" | awk '$1 + 0 == $1'` produces the output `1e2`. Try it with input of "1.2" as well.

Comment: You are right. Awk is weakly typed. Variables have no data type. By issues I meant problems. string + string != number.

Comment: still not sure where you see an issue or a problem with the way awk treats strings or numbers. Could you give a concrete example where awk doesn't behave sensibly?

Comment: No, awk is sensible. It makes sense not to calculate strings though python would do: foo + bar = foobar which is ok for them.

Comment: The only issue is if the value is actually "0", it won't be printed

Comment: That's not the only issue, it'll also truncate strings that start with a number to just the number part so if $2 was 3c then '$2 + 0' would be 3 and so the record would print.

Comment: wrt the posted update of `awk '/[a-z]/{next}{print $0}' file.txt`, there's no need for `{print $0}` and you need to specifically check the field you're working on, $2, so it should be written as `awk '$2~/[a-z]/{next}' but this would allow fields with punctuation marks or other non-alphanumeric characters and has other issues.

Answer (score 9):

You can match using a pattern:

```
awk '$2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/'
```

If you want to allow negative values, you can do this:

```
awk '$2 ~ /^-?[0-9]+$/'
```

Comment: Thanks, but this prints fish5 which I didn't want.  I only want to print fields where the characters exclusively contain digits.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but I tried the first example and it doesn't print any of the lines now. Actually without the $ at the end it works.

Comment: @user619818 Then you have some control characters at the end of the second field in each line. `cat -v file` to see them.

Comment: @VaughnCato: no need for ` { print }`, that's what awk will do by default.

Comment: @EdMorton In my test input file the second column is last field - so newline at end.  But I thought awk stripped this?

Comment: yes, the newline is not a problem. If your second field is "7" and /^[0-9]+$/ doesn't match it but /[^0-9]+/ does, then there is an invisible (control?) character after "7".

Comment: @EdMorton  Actually I just checked.  There is a CR (0xD) at the end of each line in my input file. Maybe I also need to strip this before comparison.  AWE s answer does give me the correct result however.

Comment: AWEs answer will select the records you want from the specific input file you posted. If that's all you want then great, but if you tried it with different input you would get different results.